# Is there any time limitation for Google Calendar List api SyncToken?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

As stated in the [document](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/sync#full_sync_required_by_server), the **syncToken** can become invalid, What is the **syncToken** expiration? Is there any time limitation for **SyncToken**?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any public documentation disclosing the expiration timeframe. The [people.connections.list API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list) also uses a `syncToken` and it expires 7 days after a full sync. You could use that as a reference, though the Calendar token may behave differently.

Sometimes when developer documentation is intentionally vague about details like these is because the limits are confidential to prevent abuse. Either way you should follow the documentation's advice to react to the token expiration and request a new full sync when needed, since this is necessary whether or not you know the token lifetime. You can track a few tokens to see when they expire and reach your own conclusions.

It could also be an oversight in the documentation, so I'd also recommend clicking the "Send Feedback" button at the bottom of [the page](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/sync) to request an update. I've done so myself so hopefully it's something that they can publish.